# For loop doesn't run in worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I tried to link the common columns together but when I click a cell in PolicyComponents Sheet, the for loop doesn't run - it just exits the sub.

**Code Snippet:**

```
Sub LinkName()

Dim i As Long
Dim ShtUsedRange, ShtUsedRangeCol
Dim name As String
Dim name1 As String
Dim lookup_range As Range
Dim box


ShtUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
'Count the used rows in the Activesheet
ShtUsedRangeCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
'Count the used Column in the Activesheet

name = ActiveCell.Row
'Row of the Selected Cell

name1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(name, 1).Value
'name of the row selected

'MsgBox name1

Set lookup_range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Range("a1:z5000")
'set the range of the Policy details to search from

box = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(name1, lookup_range, 1, False)
'to match the name to the policy details

MsgBox box

For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Rows.Count Step -1

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 1).Value = box Then
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(16, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 4).Value

End If    
Next i    
End Sub
```

Comment: You are using *name* as a string type variable but assigning it the row number value. Thi9s means that *name* is *"2"* and not *2* and cannot be used when a number is required.

Comment: okay i have fixed that but when i debug going line by line, it just totally skips the for loop. @Jeeped

Comment: I'm unclear on whether my code modifications below have resolved the problem or not. If you still require some debugging help could you add any changes to your question with an edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You are using name as a string type variable but assigning it the row number value. This means that name is `"2"` and not `2` and cannot be used when a number is required. It is also never a good idea to call your variables the same as reserved words like VBA's `.Name`.
2. You are using *Step -1* but starting at *1* which means it will never go anywhere.

That should be enough to get the loop going.

```
Sub LinkName()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim ShtUsedRange, ShtUsedRangeCol
    Dim rw As Long
    Dim lu As Variant
    Dim lookup_range As Range
    Dim box As Variant


    'Count the used rows in the Activesheet
    ShtUsedRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    'Count the used Column in the Activesheet
    ShtUsedRangeCol = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    'Row of the Selected Cell
    rw = ActiveCell.Row

    'name of the row selected
    lu = ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, 1).Value

    'MsgBox lu

    'set the range of the Policy details to search from
    Set lookup_range = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyDetails").Range("a1:z5000")

    'there is no error control here if there is no match
    'to match the name to the policy details
    box = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(lu, lookup_range, 1, False)

    MsgBox box

    For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Rows.Count Step 1
        If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 1).Value = box Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Policy Viewer").Cells(16, 2) = _
              ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PolicyComponents").Cells(i, 4).Value
            'probably best to exit hte loop here unless you want to try and catch other matches
            'Exit For
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

I renamed two of your variables. I didn't know the nature of the value (number/text/date) you were actually trying to look up so I left it as a variant.

Answer (score 1):

You loop is going from `1` to the row count, but using `i` with a step of `-1`  which means you are counting backwards, never getting to `...Rows.Count`.

Change the order of your loop, going from `Rows.Count` to `1` if you want to use a step like that or use `Step 1` to count up by one (the default).